# How to I add values taken from database with a while loop into an array?

Tags: php, mysql

Additional Information
1) I have multiple records (name, age, gender), ((John, 10, Male), (Sally, 9, Female), (Jack, 12, Male)).

2) All these records are in a database.

3) I want to add these records into an array automatically with a while loop.

I tried to submit my codes with these question but it prompt that it is not properly formatted. Please help. Most welcome to give u more information if needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
foreach ($con->query("SELECT * FROM table") as $row){
    $arr[] = array(
        "name" => $row['name'],
        "age" => $row['age'],
        "gender" => $row['gender']
    );
}
```

Where `$con` is your connection, table is your table name ...

Then if you `var_dump` `$arr` you'll see array structure something like this =>

```
array (size=n) // n number of array in $arr
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'John' (length=7)
      'age' => string '10' (length=2)
      'gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Sally' (length=7)
      'age' => string '10' (length=2)
      'gender' => string 'Female' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'name' => string 'Other' (length=7)
      'age' => string '10' (length=2)
      'gender' => string 'Male' (length=4)
  // etc ...
```

Comment: What if I have a WHERE clause, how does it look like? Example, I tried adding WHERE age = '9' but when I var_dump the arr, every records still came up. Next, my string all is NULL, ["class_id"]=> NULL ["student_id"]=> NULL ["result_marks"]=> NULL

Comment: @user1436885 If you write `WHERE age=9` all records (that have age equal to 9) will return. And please write more carefully next question ...

Comment: @user1436885 if your `age` column type is `INT` you mustn't use `''` , otherwise if you have type `VARCHAR` you have to